# Debug JS Remotely vs Debug in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Some time I am getting

- Debug JS in remotely and other time
- Debug in chrome.

Now I really don't know when and how this option changes and the process to handle the scenario for Debug JS Remotely.

In my case when i click on Debug JS Remotely nothing is happening at my pc. I think it should open chrome in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think those two text means the same thing, when packager is running try access this url on your browser.

```
http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui
```

Comment: Tried that but the error message still exist. Seems no effect for debug ja remotely.